# Import inherited nested class

Tags: java, inheritance, import, inner-classes

If I declare a nested class:

```
class Outer {
    static class Nested {}
}
```

And then extend the outer class:

```
class Child extends Outer {}
```

I can reference `Nested` via `Child`:

```
new Child.Nested()
```

But I can only import `Outer.Nested`:

```
import mypackage.Outer.Nested;  // valid
import mypackage.Child.Nested;  // compile error
```

Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score -2):

The inconsistency is due to the keyword `static` in the declaration.[difference between nested class and inner class](https://medium.com/the-kotlin-primer/nested-and-inner-classes-b300243d036d)

As a nested class is a static class defined inside another class. It is not bound to a specific instance of the outer class.

Comment: I left out the access modifiers to keep things simple, but you would still need the import in the same package if you wanted to, say, construct a `new Nested()` without specifying the outer class. Same goes for static imports.

Comment: @Teletubbies As far as I can tell, this has nothing to do with inner classes. `Nested` is a static nested class, but you can reference `Nested` via the `Parent` **or** `Child` type (type, not instance) when _instantiating_, yet you can only reference it via the `Parent` type when _importing_. Does that not seem inconsistent?

Comment: @shmosel To make it stranger, `import static mypackage.Child.Nested;` appears to work (at least on JDK 20).

Comment: @Slaw You mean `import static mypackage.Child.Nested.*;`? Didn't work for me in Java 8.

Comment: @shmosel Nope. Just `import static mypackage.Child.Nested;`. Having that import, and only that import, let me do `new Nested()`. It compiled and ran without error.

Comment: @Slaw I didn't even know that was a valid construct. How is it different from the non-static import?

Comment: @shmosel I had no idea either until just now. The only difference I can see is that [non-static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1) have a syntax of `import TypeName;`, whereas [static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.3) have a syntax of `import static TypeName.Identifier;`. I believe it's the `Identifier` part that makes the difference.